# What is the relation between Nuclear magnetic resonance (NMR) and electron paramagnetic resonance (EPR)?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, nuclear-physics, physical-chemistry

It seems to me that the basic principles are exactly the same, right? Then I am puzzled that the former was awarded a nobel prize while the later not.

I noticed a similar question here [What's the difference between NMR and EPR?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/171256/whats-the-difference-between-nmr-and-epr)

It seems that the difference is purely quantitative, in the frequency.

Comment: Could you explain how this question is not a duplicate of the one you linked?

Comment: My question is more about the nobel prize

Comment: Why the prize commitee considered one worthy and the other not is the decision of the commitee, and not really a question that is objectively answerable by anyone other than the commitee.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the maths and equations are pretty much identical except in H NMR you would use the gyromagnetic ratio for a proton, while in EPR you use the data for an electron. Both are spin 1/2 systems.

In terms of medical imaging it is easier to pick H2O via pulse NMR (rather than continuous field i.e what chemists do for molecules etc) than observe free radicals. However there are plenty of free radicals in the body. In fact most of the metalloproteins that use copper can exhibit free radical chemistry - or redox cofactors for electron transfer chemistry to name but two.